# BuildConfig is defined multiple times in Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on an android application with Xamarin and I keep getting this error when I try to build.

```
Error       Error in obj\Debug\130\lp\0\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/getkeepsafe/relinker/BuildConfig.class:
Type com.getkeepsafe.relinker.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\130\lp\0\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/getkeepsafe/relinker/BuildConfig.class, obj\Debug\130\lp\132\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/getkeepsafe/relinker/BuildConfig.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\130\lp\0\jl\bin\classes.jar
```

I've tried looking for duplicates in packages, deleting obj and bin folders, clean+build and rebuild and many other solutions from the internet and nothing seems to solve it.

Comment: Is this on compile time or runtime, Also did you make some changes after which this showed up? Add more relevant stack trace if possible

Comment: This is compile time. The changes that i made was replacing an existing library's code with a newer library, and after making all the code changes, i got this on build.

Comment: Could you please post the full log of this problem? And how can we reproduce this problem?

Comment: Here are the full logs of the error: https://pastebin.com/5uDHUbGZ . As for reproducing it I am not sure how, since the app was working fine and after a big code overhaul it stopped working.